# Row vector multiplication?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given two row vectors, $(a, b, c )$, and $( x, y, z )$, does the operation of creating a new row vector in the format $$( ax, by, cz )$$ have a name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Just call it element wise multiplication.
- Some people also like to use [Hadamard Product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Hadamard_product).
- Else, 
  $$p=(a,b,c)\quad q=(x,y,z)$$
  $$N=\sum_{i=1}^3p_iq_ie_i$$
- Alternately,

$$N=diag(a)\times b$$

Comment: Hadamard product; that seems to be it.

Comment: Could you explain what `e` is?

Comment: $e_i$ is (AFAIK) universal notation for a vector with $1$ at the $i^{th}$ location and $0$ everywhere else. So, $e_1 \in \mathbb{R}^3$ is $[1 \quad 0\quad 0]^T$.